# Magento 2.3.4 showing Magento ver. UNKNOWN in admin panel

Tags: magento2.3.4

I suddenly noticed at the bottom right corner of the magento admin panel and found very strange that instead of showing Magento version, it is showing me Magento ver. UNKNOWN.

Unable to figure out what makes it so. Here is my composer.json file if it works:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.14.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~4.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.5.3",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.4.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.4",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    },
    "require": {
        "mageplaza/module-smtp": "^1.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following value is missing in composer.json compared with fresh Magento 2.3.4 setup:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.4"
},
```

It might be caused by an outdated version of `composer/composer` being installed in your Magento shop (`run composer show | grep composer/composer`), or even an outdated git version (`git --version`).

Please refer to the [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22445)

Comment: Agreed, but while comparing with git version. I find lot more lines missing in require object. Can I copy the same from git? I have just one ext installed which I will do again.

Answer (score 0):

That look like composer version wrong, but if your magento running well, and you just need to display proper version, change it directly in source file:

**vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php**

```
public function getVersion()
    {
        $this->version = $this->version ?: $this->cache->load(self::VERSION_CACHE_KEY);
        if (!$this->version) {
            if (!($this->version = $this->getSystemPackageVersion())) {
                if ($this->getComposerInformation()->isMagentoRoot()) {
                    $this->version = $this->getComposerInformation()->getRootPackage()->getPrettyVersion();
                } else {
                    $this->version = '2.4.6'; // YOUR VERSION NUMBER IS HERE
                }
            }
            $this->cache->save($this->version, self::VERSION_CACHE_KEY, [Config::CACHE_TAG]);
        }
        return $this->version;
    }
```